# Modelling glass half full vs half empty using logic

Tags: logic

Suppose we have a glass of water, and it is filled till half. One could either say, it is half  full or it is half empty. These are two distinct propositions, but are complement to each other in some sense. Does there exist some well established model of logic studying these type of relationship between propositions?

Another example of this type, my computers window breaks, but I then take happiness in the rest of it's parts being functioning. Seems to me that optimism vs distinction thing is full of these type of complementation of statements.

I've seen [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/83114/the-glass-half-full-glass-half-empty-distinction-beyond-fregean-semantics), but  I felt it was in a different direction and there were no good replies. In regards to the first example, I also [found this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54421/wheres-the-red-herring-in-arguing-that-i-see-it-as-a-glass-half-full-rather-th)

---

Note: I don't believe the glass half full, half empty thing is should neccesarily be the same proposition. For instance, suppose we say the glass is filled with $x$ liter of water, then it would be equivalent to saying, assuming the glass has capacity of $1$ liter,  the glass has still $1-x$ liter of water to be filled with.

Comment: The usual point is that these are *not* two distinct propositions, they are the same proposition differently phrased. The difference in phrasing reflects what Frege called tone or coloring, an emotional attitude towards what the proposition states, part of what is now called its [connotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connotation). You cannot model that with predicate logic alone, you need modal operators for expressing propositional attitudes.

Comment: @Conifold, headshot! Quick, painless ... *Allah rahim*.

Comment: Well, for starters, the OP seems ta know his stuff, pretty well at that. I'm quite pleased, and at the same time, rather offended, at the way the world treats us. One person *at least* didn't die of measles. The sun, water, air, soil, some fertilizer, and we get ... Simple, yea/nay?

Answer (score 1):

**Fuzzy Logic**

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-fuzzy-logic-are-t/

> **Charles Elkan, an assistant professor of computer science and engineering at the University of California at San Diego, offers the following definition:**

> "Fuzzy logic is a generalization of standard logic, in which a concept can possess a degree of truth anywhere between 0.0 and 1.0. Standard logic applies only to concepts that are completely true (having degree of truth 1.0) or completely false (having degree of truth 0.0). Fuzzy logic is supposed to be used for reasoning about inherently vague concepts, such as 'tallness.' For example, we might say that 'President Clinton is tall,' with degree of truth of 0.9.

If the glass is half full and half empty then in a fuzzy logic model it has degrees of membership as follows: 0.5 fullness, 0.5 emptiness.

Fuzzy logic has practical use in engineering control systems. In the domain of neural networks the human brain (philosophical body-mind) generates crisp distinctions (distinct words) and maps those terms to  items of recognition with indistinct or vague attributes such as the concepts of tall or short; or hot or warm or cold; etc.

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to assign any logic to subjective expectations considering the fullness of the glass. Sometimes a full glass is preferred and sometimes an empty glass would be better.

Therefore we have to examine only the known facts about the glass. We already know that the glass is filled to 50% capacity,

- If the glass is in the middle of filling process, it is half-full.
- If the glass is in the middle of emptying process, it is half-empty.
- If we don't know which way the glass is going, both statements are equally true.
- If we know the given volume of water, then the glass is half-full (water has been added, none removed, an incomplete filling process).

Comment: How are the propositions I put in the post any subjective? Mathematically speaking, one statement is, the glass has "x" quantity of water and the other is, the glass has 1-x quantity (see edit of post)

Comment: You mentioned happiness and optimism, which are referring to the subjective attitude of the observer.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Where is this 1 - x coming from? Both states (half -full and -empty) would imply the glass has (MaxCapacity / 2) amount of liquid.

Comment: In specific case of half full vs half empty yes, but in more gneeral case of, 1/3 full, vs 2/3 empty it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of Logic, `F + E = 1`, or using predicate logic, `HF(g)` means the glass (g) is Full (HF). Half-full implies half-empty and that's just an arithmetic curiosity.

Two facts to consider:

1. The fact that you associate such behavior with optimism/pessimism is not a subject of Logic, but of Psychology.
2. In addition, it is possible that the amount of pessimism and optimism about a same fact don't add up to 1, that's how the mind works. For example, supposing that the level of lake X is 80%full and 20%empty, such configuration will not trigger any optimism or pessimism in you, so, the sum of optimism and pessimism adds up to 0.